# How do I make an clickable image link in GitHub Flavoured Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

How do I make an image in my GitHub markdown that, when clicked, visits a URL?

The equivalent of this HTML:

```
<a href="/destination">
  <img src="/some/image.svg"/>
</a>
```

I have read the [StackOverflow markdown question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link) and tried the syntax used there:

```
[![Build status][https://github.com/myorg/myapp/actions/workflows/tests.yaml/badge.svg]][https://github.com/myorg/myapp/actions]
```

However that syntax doesn't render properly on GitHub.

**How do I make an clickable image link in GitHub Markdown?**

Answer (score 2):

**Answering my own question to help others:**

It turned out this slightly different syntax works:

It's basically a regular link:

```
[link text](https://destination)
```

With the link text being replaced with an image. Working version:

```
[![Alt text](https://someimage.svg)](https://destination)
```