# Add image with link to Github flavored Markdown in README

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

How can I add a clickable image with link into GitHub `README.md` file?
For example a "Buy me a Donut" badge:
[image]

The image is an SVG file, so it should be also possible to set a specific width.
The resulting HTML should look like this:

```html
<a href="https://www.buymeacoffee.com/tobse" rel="nofollow">
    <img alt="Buy me a Donut" 
         src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tobsef/tobsef/master/img/buy-me-a-donut.svg" 
         width="245px"
    ">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For [Github flavored Markdown](https://docs.github.com/de/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax), it's possible in two different ways.

#### 1. In Markdown Syntax

```markdown
[buy-me-a-donut]: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/tobse
[![Buy me a Donut](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tobsef/tobsef/master/img/buy-me-a-donut.svg)][buy-me-a-donut]
```

The the content in the first bracket (`[Buy me a Donut]`) is the image `alt` attribute.
In this example, the link is separated as `[buy-me-a-donut]`.This is optional, but keeps the markdown file clean. You can also add the image in one line:

```markdown
[![Buy me a Donut](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tobsef/tobsef/master/img/buy-me-a-donut.svg)][https://www.buymeacoffee.com/tobse]
```

Syntax:

```markdown
[![Alt attribute](https://link-to-your-image.svg)][https://external-link/]
```

#### 2. With inline HMTL

Github flavored also supports a small subset of HTML. So it's possible to simply use a `img` element:

```markdown
[buy-me-a-donut]: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/tobse
[<img alt="Buy me a Donut" width="245px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tobsef/tobsef/master/img/buy-me-a-donut.svg" />][buy-me-a-donut]
```

With this syntax, you can also add additional attributes like `width="245px"` or even change the layout with alignment by `align="center"`.
If you prefer the compact version, you can also write it in one line:

```markdown
[<img alt="Buy me a Donut" width="245px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tobsef/tobsef/master/img/buy-me-a-donut.svg" />][https://www.buymeacoffee.com/tobse]
```

Comment: I don't think that this particular syntax as suggested works anymore:
`[![Alt attribute](https://link-to-your-image.svg)][https://external-link/]`. An up-to-date syntax working for Github can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73485945/1509695).